# Как вывести первый элемент без задержки с setInterval()

Tags: javascript

Случилась проблема с тем, что при загрузке страницы и первого элемента в `setInterval()` возникает задержка, а мне она не нужна. Я попробовал решить её путём изменения элемента без `setInterval()` с добавлением +1 значения в переменную i, но мне кажется, что есть более лучший способ для этой цели.

```js
const texting = document.querySelector('#texting')
var i = 0
var j = 0
var tips = [
  'You want me, I want you, baby',
  "My sugarboo, I'm levitating",
  'The Milky Way is liberating',
  'Yeah, yeah, yeah',
]

function start() {
  do {
    texting.textContent = tips[0] // избавление от задержки
    i++
    j++
  } while (j == 0)
  setInterval(function() {
    texting.textContent = tips[i]
    if (i == 3) {
      i = -1
    }
    i++
  }, 2000)
}
start()
```

```html
<span id="texting">Подождите...</span>
```

Comment: а зачем вообще цикл `do...while` тут, если он всего одну итерацию делает?

Comment: @Grundy он для того, чтобы вывести 1-ый элемент массива без задержки.

Comment: так а цикл зачем? если ты его уберешь - ничего не поменяется. Заодно и лишнюю переменную уберешь

Comment: @Grundy, да, уже догадался.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно вам подойдёт, если вы просто добавите первую строку перед вызовом функции.

```
const texting = document.querySelector('#texting')
var i = 0
var j = 0
var tips = [
  'You want me, I want you, baby',
  "My sugarboo, I'm levitating",
  'The Milky Way is liberating',
  'Yeah, yeah, yeah',
]

function start() {
  do {
    i++
    j++
  } while (j == 0)
  setInterval(function() {
    texting.textContent = tips[i]
    if (i == 3) {
      i = -1
    }
    i++
  }, 2000)
}
texting.textContent = tips[0]
start()
```

Comment: Да, будет лучше если убрать do..while и i начать с 1, а не с 0.